# Check if a query on OCR is selective

Tags: soql

I have a query that looks like this:

SELECT ContactId, OpportunityId
        FROM OpportunityContactRole
        WHERE ContactId IN: conAccountMap.keyset()

I checked the QueryPlan and it looks like following:

[image]

OCR is a junction object and I am worried about the query becoming non-selective. Please let me know your views.

Comment: The question is slightly different, but the answer is exactly the same: if the first item on the Query Plan is an index, it's selective.

Comment: @sfdcfox Gotit. but just wanted to confirm since it is a junction object.